# Resources cannot be loaded from epub in epubjs

Tags: javascript, android, ionic2, epub, epub.js

I'm using epubjs in a ionic app for a simple epub reader. I'm having a problem with the resources of the epub I need to open. When I try to load the file 48666 resources (any of the file) couldn't be loaded and when I see the dev tools in network I see this

```
http://localhost:8100/OEBPS/css/idGeneratedStyles.css:8100/OEBPS/image/90767.png:1 GET
```

(lots of this)

with this errors in epubjs

```
EPUBJS.Render.Iframe.load @ render_iframe.js:102
EPUBJS.Renderer.load @ renderer.js:167
(anonymous) @ renderer.js:143
tryCatch @ -internal.js:215
invokeCallback @ -internal.js:230
publish @ -internal.js:198
flush @ asap.js:83
```

I don't know if I'm loading the file wrong or if the file should be exported differently but I don't know what else to do.

Appreciate your help guys and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about this post... my mistake... Didn't know that the pagination with epub.js loads all the resources and that makes the app very slow.